# Proof verification for differential equation for certain theorem!

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

Theorem
Hypothesis:
Suppose $u$ is any solution to $n$-th order homogeneous differential equation whereas $v$ is any solution to the $n$-th order non homogeneous differential equation. Then, we can conclude that $y=u+v$ is also a solution to the non homogeneous differential equation

Prove that $u$ is any solution to the following second order homogeneous differential equation.

$$a_{0}(x)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+a_{1}(x)\frac{dy}{dx}+a_{2}(x)y=0$$

and $v$ is any solution to the following second order non-homogeneous differential equation,

$$a_{0}(x)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+a_{1}(x)\frac{dy}{dx}+a_{2}(x)y=F(x)$$

then, $u+v$ is also a solution to the second order non-homogeneous differential equation!

My work is then,

let $y=u$ ,$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{du}{dx}$, $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}$

So, $$a_{0}(x)\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}+a_{1}(x)\frac{du}{dx}+a_{2}(x)u=0$$

Suppose $y=v$ ,$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dv}{dx}$, $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d^2v}{dx^2}$

$$a_{0}(x)\frac{d^2v}{dx^2}+a_{1}(x)\frac{dv}{dx}+a_{2}(x)v=F(x)$$

Adding these two solutions together we would have $y=u+v$ as the solution to the non homogeneous differential equation!

Is this the right way to do the proof?

Comment: Looks OK to me!

Comment: Basically.... yeah. If it is a homework problem, then I would recommend showing all the steps since the idea, as you have shown, is not too complicated so they tend to dock points on those kinds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $w = u + v.$ Then \begin{eqnarray}a_{0}(x)\frac{d^2w}{dx^2}+a_{1}(x)\frac{dw}{dx}+a_{2}(x)w &&=&& a_0(x) (u'' + v'') + a_1(x)(u' + v') + a_2(x)(u+v) \\
&& = && [a_0(x)u'' + a_1(x)u' + a_2(x)u] \\&&+&& [a_0(x)v'' + a_1(x)v' + a_2(x)v] \\ && = && 0 + F(x)
\end{eqnarray}

and that immediately gives you your answer.